# TableViewCell not displays the height I set as a constraint

Tags: ios, xcode, uitableview, autolayout

I managed to get this work in the past but now I cannot remember how I did it. I have a UITableView with a dynamic cell and in it, I have an UIView with a height of 174 as a constraint. However, after running the app, it displays the UIView with less height than I defined and also I am getting this error: Warning once only: Detected a case where constraints ambiguously suggest a height of zero for tableviewcell cell's. We're considering the collapse unintentional and using standard height instead:

[image]

Those are the constraints I have in the UIView:

[image]

I am not able to find a fix for this.

Comment: Bottom constraint is missing. Add Bottom space and everything will work then

Comment: Oh you might just also align your `UIView` both `vertical` and `horizontally` in the `centre` since it takes up the whole `cell `

Comment: I have tried both options but the issue persists. I am going to try what ktr kathir said and I will see what happens. Thank you anyway.

Comment: @AdriánT95 both Shruthi's comment and kathir's answer will work. But the better approach is the one suggested in the comments.

Comment: @AdriánT95 use `UITableViewAutomaticDimension` instead of `178` it will set height according to content. I have already made edit to answer

Comment: Check property of your cell `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false`, if you wanna automatic layout for them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this datasource

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        return 178
}
```